# Mathematics series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please can anybody explain how to resolve this step-by-step?

$$\sum_{r=10}^{100}(r-10)$$

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $$\sum_{r=10}^{100}(r-10)=\sum_{r=0}^{90}r=\frac{90(90+1)}{2}.$$ The latter identity is a well-known formula of Gauss.

Comment: At the first summation: $r=10$

Comment: Correct, silly typo, thanks.

Comment: Thanka all. But what is final answer? And, why we take first term = 1, actually first term is 0 ( r-10 , so 10-10 = 0 )?

Comment: Wauw, you are really lazy, just compute $\frac{90(91)}{2}=45\cdot 91=45\cdot (100-9)=4500-405=4095$. You will have to learn to do some work yourself.

Comment: Brother, misunderstand. Actually I'm not good with maths, so I'm asked that, why we add (90+1) instead of (90+0) because first term is equal to 0? Hope you can kindly understand. ( r1 = 0, r2 = 1, r3 = 3...)

Comment: That is the gauss formula: Suppose you want to calculate $$1+2+3+4+\dots +(n-1)+n.$$
Write down $$n+(n-1)+\dots +4+3+2+1$$ as well. Then add them vertically, $(1+n) +(2+n-1) + \dots +(n-1+2) + (n+1)$. This is equal to $n$ times $(n+1)$, but we counted the sum twice, hence the sum is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: you can write the same as

$$\sum_{r=10}^{100}(r-10)=\sum_{10\le r\le 100}(r-10)=\sum_{0\le r-10\le 90}(r-10)=\sum_{r=0}^{90}r$$

You can solve it from here?